# How to generate start and end date vectors by month/week but make the last end date of the vector ending with today?

Tags: r, date, datetime, sequence, lubridate

I'm trying to generate a vector for an api import package which accepts the following arguments

```
date.from   
Start date in YYYY-MM-DD.

date.to 
End date in YYYY-MM-DD.
```

Since the date range is quite big and I'm trying to get the data without sampling, I have to split the request into smaller ones, otherwise I get error 400 and an advice to try smaller date range.

My code looks like this:

```
library(lubridate)

today <- Sys.Date()

start_date <- seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"),  as.Date(today), by = "months")
end_date <- seq(as.Date("2013-02-01"),  as.Date(today), by = "months")-1
```

It results in 2 sets of dates for start and end dates each, however the set with start date has 1st day of the current month, but end date has nothing because current month isn't complete (today is 2020-09-12)

```
> start_date
 [1] "2013-01-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01" "2013-04-01" "2013-05-01" "2013-06-01" "2013-07-01"
 [8] "2013-08-01" "2013-09-01" "2013-10-01" "2013-11-01" "2013-12-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-02-01"
[15] "2014-03-01" "2014-04-01" "2014-05-01" "2014-06-01" "2014-07-01" "2014-08-01" "2014-09-01"
[22] "2014-10-01" "2014-11-01" "2014-12-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-02-01" "2015-03-01" "2015-04-01"
[29] "2015-05-01" "2015-06-01" "2015-07-01" "2015-08-01" "2015-09-01" "2015-10-01" "2015-11-01"
[36] "2015-12-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-02-01" "2016-03-01" "2016-04-01" "2016-05-01" "2016-06-01"
[43] "2016-07-01" "2016-08-01" "2016-09-01" "2016-10-01" "2016-11-01" "2016-12-01" "2017-01-01"
[50] "2017-02-01" "2017-03-01" "2017-04-01" "2017-05-01" "2017-06-01" "2017-07-01" "2017-08-01"
[57] "2017-09-01" "2017-10-01" "2017-11-01" "2017-12-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-03-01"
[64] "2018-04-01" "2018-05-01" "2018-06-01" "2018-07-01" "2018-08-01" "2018-09-01" "2018-10-01"
[71] "2018-11-01" "2018-12-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-05-01"
[78] "2019-06-01" "2019-07-01" "2019-08-01" "2019-09-01" "2019-10-01" "2019-11-01" "2019-12-01"
[85] "2020-01-01" "2020-02-01" "2020-03-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-05-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-07-01"
[92] "2020-08-01" "2020-09-01"
```

```
> end_date
 [1] "2013-01-30" "2013-03-02" "2013-03-30" "2013-04-30" "2013-05-30" "2013-06-30" "2013-07-30"
 [8] "2013-08-30" "2013-09-30" "2013-10-30" "2013-11-30" "2013-12-30" "2014-01-30" "2014-03-02"
[15] "2014-03-30" "2014-04-30" "2014-05-30" "2014-06-30" "2014-07-30" "2014-08-30" "2014-09-30"
[22] "2014-10-30" "2014-11-30" "2014-12-30" "2015-01-30" "2015-03-02" "2015-03-30" "2015-04-30"
[29] "2015-05-30" "2015-06-30" "2015-07-30" "2015-08-30" "2015-09-30" "2015-10-30" "2015-11-30"
[36] "2015-12-30" "2016-01-30" "2016-03-01" "2016-03-30" "2016-04-30" "2016-05-30" "2016-06-30"
[43] "2016-07-30" "2016-08-30" "2016-09-30" "2016-10-30" "2016-11-30" "2016-12-30" "2017-01-30"
[50] "2017-03-02" "2017-03-30" "2017-04-30" "2017-05-30" "2017-06-30" "2017-07-30" "2017-08-30"
[57] "2017-09-30" "2017-10-30" "2017-11-30" "2017-12-30" "2018-01-30" "2018-03-02" "2018-03-30"
[64] "2018-04-30" "2018-05-30" "2018-06-30" "2018-07-30" "2018-08-30" "2018-09-30" "2018-10-30"
[71] "2018-11-30" "2018-12-30" "2019-01-30" "2019-03-02" "2019-03-30" "2019-04-30" "2019-05-30"
[78] "2019-06-30" "2019-07-30" "2019-08-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-10-30" "2019-11-30" "2019-12-30"
[85] "2020-01-30" "2020-03-01" "2020-03-30" "2020-04-30" "2020-05-30" "2020-06-30" "2020-07-30"
[92] "2020-08-30"
```

Which I'm later feeding through the loop like this:

```
metrika_sources <- list()
for (i in 1:length(start_date)) {
   for (j in 1:length(end_date)) {
      rym_sources <-
         rym_get_data(
            counters = "******",
            date.from = start_date[i],
            date.to = end_date[j],
            dimensions = "ym:s:date,ym:s:lastTrafficSource,ym:s:lastSourceEngine,ym:s:deviceCategory,ym:s:UTMSource,ym:s:UTMMedium,ym:s:UTMCampaign",
            metrics = "ym:s:visits,ym:s:pageviews,ym:s:users,ym:s:bounceRate,ym:s:pageDepth,ym:s:avgVisitDurationSeconds,ym:s:productPurchasedQuantity",
            sort = "-ym:s:date",
            login = "******",
            token.path = "*****",
            accuracy = "full",
         )
   }
}
```

Is there a way to make the sequence finish with the today's or yesterday's date?

Thank you for helping out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could append `today` and `today - 1` to start and end date respectively.

```
today <- Sys.Date()
start_date <- c(start_date, today)
end_date <- c(end_date, today - 1)
```

Comment: You're the MVP and a genius, sir!

I've slightly edited your code like this 

`start_date <- seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"),  as.Date(today), by = "months")
end_date <- seq(as.Date("2013-02-01"),  as.Date(today), by = "months")-1
start_date <- c(start_date)
end_date <- c(end_date, today)`

which resulted in 2 neat and evenly set of date sequences with 93 dates each. But unfortunately the looping through still returns error 400 :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know about why/how of 400 error. I tried to answer the question  `to make the sequence finish with the today's or yesterday's date?`.

Comment: Yes, I've further addressed the question to package maintainer, so your answer did help!